# What is wrong with my approach on a custom way of creating Gabor-filter convolution kernels?

Tags: neural-networks, optimization, gradient-descent, convolution, filter

*Disclosure*: I am not a prominent mathematician (current bachelor student) like others on this website and my approach has been mostly pragmatic. Please do tell me if I can improve the formulation of my question and/or should provide more background information.

For the past few weeks I have been investigating in what I feel like is a smart way of improving on the way the first convolution layer of a neural network is created.
In the 'vanilla' way, the convolution kernels are simply initialized randomly and the kernel 'weights' are being tweaked respectively through back-propagation.

In a fairly [recent blog post by Distill Pub](https://distill.pub/2020/circuits/early-vision/#conv2d0), in which they investigate the shape and behaviour of early convolution kernels of various popular neural networks, it is found that rougly 44% of the initial kernels are very similar to [Gabor filters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabor_filter).
My idea is to constrain the 'hypothesis space' of the first convolution layer in such a network to just be Gabor filters where the neural network may tweak the parameters of the Gabor filter rather than the raw kernel 'weights'.

The formula I use for (real valued) Gabor filters is as follows:

[image]

where $x' = x\cos(\theta) + y\sin(\theta)$ and $y' = -x\sin(\theta) + y\cos(\theta)$

I have spent quite a lot of time on implementing this idea, however I cannot get the gradient descent to work properly. I suspect there is something fundamentally wrong with my approach, which is why I am turning to the experts.

**My current experiment setup** Currently, I have an input image that I convolve with a predefined (hardcoded) kernel, with theta set to $\pi/4$ (the other variables may be considered constant) to produce an output $x$. This makes it so that I can see what kernel would yield output $x$.
Next, I initialize the Gabor filter to be updated with a theta of $- \pi / 4$, which I expect to be corrected to the actual value of $\pi/4$. At the start of the training loop, when convolved with the image the convolution does not yield input $x$.
Through back propagation the $\theta$ parameter should now be tweaked in order to obtain output $x$. I am currently using a flavor of RMSE, but this should not be important.

**Results**
In actuality, this is not what happens at all. The $\theta$ parameter is being updated, albeit in a sensible direction (as measured by the loss value), at some point is jumps back to having a
terrible loss value and this cycle seems to continue indefinitely. I have tried implementing Momentum without any better results.

My main suspicion are the cycling components of the partial derivative of the Gabor function, which I have let Wolfram Alpha compute for me [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=partial%20derivative%20of%20exp%28-%28%28xcos%28theta%29%20%2B%20ysin%28theta%29%29%5E2%20%2B%20z%5E2%20*%20%28-xsin%28theta%29%20%2B%20ycos%28theta%29%29%5E2%29%2F%282%20%5Csigma%5E2%29%29cos%20%282%5Cpi%20%28xcos%28theta%29%20%2B%20ysin%28theta%29%29%2F%20%5Clambda%20%2B%20k%29%20with%20respect%20to%20theta). Furthermore, could it be that the Gabor function does not have a nice reachable minimum with respect to $\theta$.

Now to my overarching question. Where does this break down? Does the partial derivative just not posses the right properties for it to find a proper global minimum? Did I simply make a mistake in the code, since this should theoretically be possible? How do I proceed to debug my approach?

Note: I have omitted any code here, as I am more interested in the theoretical feasibility of my approach rather than an implementation.

Comment: the RHS of your equation doesn't contain theta

Comment: @shimao I had forgotten a small part of the equation. Thank you, I have since updated it.

Comment: it's usually better not to parameterize "cyclic" parameters like theta directly. try having learnable parameters for "$\cos(\theta)$" and "$\sin(\theta)$", and normalize as needed

Comment: @shimao Great suggestion. Would you mind eloborating what 'normalization' means in this case? I am having a hard time picturing how it all would work out. Does this also mean that I should have the theta constant, and add a constant $a$ (the scale of the $cos(\theta)$ term and learn that instead?

Comment: I just mean, have two learned parameters, say $\alpha, \beta$, and divide by $\alpha^2 + \beta^2$ to obtain $\cos \theta$ and $\sin \theta$. Alternatively, you could perform projected gradient descent directly on $\sin$ and $\cos$, renormalizing after every gradient step.